# can't start x11vnc without attached monitor

Tags: debian, ubuntu, x11, vnc, x11vnc

I'd like to setup `x11vnc` (or any other vnc server) to start at boot-time. The display manager is `kdm`, the distribution is Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

When I try to start x11vnc, I'm getting this errors:

```
$ x11vnc -rfbauth /var/run/xauth/A:0-crWk72  -rfbport 5901
 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbauth
 passing arg to libvncserver: /var/run/xauth/A:0-crWk72
 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbport
 passing arg to libvncserver: 5901
 x11vnc version: 0.9.12 lastmod: 2010-09-09  pid: 2828
 XOpenDisplay("") failed.
 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...

 *** XOpenDisplay failed. No -display or DISPLAY.
 *** Trying ":0" in 4 seconds.  Press Ctrl-C to abort.
 *** 1 2 3 4 
 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
 Trying again with unset XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME ...
```

I've tried installing `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` in order to avoid issues with no screen attached, but so far with no success.

Comment: have you tried to install xvfb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came up with following solution:

1. `sudo apt-get install x11vnc xserver-xorg-video-dummy`
2. check `/etc/default/grub` that it includes `nomodeset` flag:

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`
3. Create (or modify) `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, modify `USER` and `LISTEN` address according to your settings.

> ```
> Section "Monitor"
> Identifier "Monitor0"
> HorizSync 28.0-80.0
> VertRefresh 48.0-75.0
> # 1680x1050 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 65.22 kHz; pclk: 147.14 MHz
> Modeline "1680x1050_60.00" 147.14 1680 1784 1968 2256 1050 1051 1054 1087 -HSync +Vsync
> EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>   Identifier "Card0"
>   Driver "dummy"
>   VideoRam 256000
> EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
> DefaultDepth 24
> Identifier "Screen0"
> Device "Card0"
> Monitor "Monitor0"
>     SubSection "Display"
>     Depth 24
>     Modes "1680x1050"    
>     EndSubSection
> EndSection
> ```

You can [generate your own resolution](http://www.arachnoid.com/modelines/index.html).

4 - create service script in `/etc/init.d/vncserver`

```
#!/bin/sh -e
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          vncserver
# Required-Start:    networking
# Default-Start:     3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 6
### END INIT INFO

PATH="$PATH:/usr/X11R6/bin/" CMD="/usr/bin/x11vnc"

# The Username:Group that will run VNC 
export USER="your_username"

# The display that VNC will use DISPLAY="1"

# Color depth (between 8 and 32) DEPTH="16"

# The Desktop geometry to use.
#GEOMETRY="<WIDTH>x<HEIGHT>"
#GEOMETRY="800x600" GEOMETRY="1680x1050"
#GEOMETRY="1280x1024"

# The name that the VNC Desktop will have. NAME="my-vnc-server"

PORT=5900 
LISTEN="192.168.1.10"


OPTIONS="-xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -listen ${LISTEN} -name ${NAME} -depth ${DEPTH} -geometry ${GEOMETRY} :${DISPLAY} -auth guess
-usepw ~/.vnc/passwd -rfbport ${PORT} -forever -bg -oa /var/log/x11vnc.log"

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in start) echo ${OPTIONS} log_action_begin_msg "Starting vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISPLAY}" su ${USER} -c "${CMD} ${OPTIONS}" ;;

stop) log_action_begin_msg "Stoping vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISPLAY}" su ${USER} -c "${CMD} -kill :${DISPLAY}" ;;

restart) $0 stop $0 start ;; esac

exit 0
```

Comment: the only problem with this is that dummy driver won't use specified resolution: `DUMMY(0): Not using default mode "1680x1050" (insufficient memory for mode)`. When the monitor is connected the nvidia card doesn't have problem with the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The following always gets me with a working vnc session quickly:

```
apt-get install vnc4server x11-xserver-utils xserver-xorg-video-dummy xterm wm2
```

I added x11-xserver-utils and xserver-xorg-video-dummy in case X11 is not yet installed on your system and you want to avoid having a full X11 install. However this point is most likely irrelevant in your case, just added it in case someone else finds it useful.

I added xterm and wm2 in case you want a simple setup and not a full blown gnome session or similar. If that is the case then under your user account run vnc4server in order to auto create ~/.vnc/xstartup. Then kill it and edit ~/.vnc/xstartup and add the following 2 lines to the bottom.

```
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
wm2 &
```

And run vnc4server again.

Otherwise just running vnc4server under your own account should suffice.
When started for the first time the vncserver will ask you to create a password, use that password to connect from a remote system.

On the remote system install something like xtightvncviewer and use it to connect to your vnc server:

```
apt-get install xtightvncviewer
xtightvncviewer 192.0.2.1:1   [1]
```

1 - See http://www.iana.org/go/rfc5737 on why to use this ip range in documentation

Comment: I've posted mine solution, it's more complicated and right now works with KDE and resolution 1360x768. I will have a look at `wm2` it looks interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @Tombart There's no difference between `x11vnc` and `x11vnc`, *literally*.