# Start X11vnc on boot at SLIM login window

Tags: x11, vnc, slim

Debian 7.7 Wheezy, xorg, SLIM, i3

I'm unable to have `x11vnc -usepw -forever` started with SLIM, to offer a vnc connection on boot, as I do not have a monitor attached to the computer. I tried to add `sessionstart_cmd   /usr/bin/x11vnc -usepw -forever` to the `/etc/slim.conf` but that didn't seem to help.
I have a `ssh` service running on boot, so I thought I could just `ssh` to the machine and start `x11vnc` then use the remote desktop connection, but the command fails as it is unable to `x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":0", it cannot continue.` (tried display 0-9)..

How can I enable x11vnc on boot or start it via ssh?

Comment: Have you seen [this Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78103/cant-start-x11vnc-without-attached-monitor)?

Comment: yes but the display manager differs, I didn't quite understand the first posted solution so I can't get to a solution myself and the second solution is for `vnc4server`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with my setup on an OUYA. I have the SLIM login window running Xfce4, and I also have SSH too. I found the MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE file (/var/run/slim.auth), and I was able to connect to the display right away after running the command in SSH. The command that worked for me was:

```
    x11vnc -auth /var/run/slim.auth
```

I hope this will yield the result you were looking for.